# JQuery mobile: Tap event on listview item also fires hidden object event

Tags: jquery, events, listview, mobile, hidden

I'm having a problem with a tap event on a dynamically-generated listview. When I select the first item in the list, the actions are fires, one of which is to unhide an object nearby. The problem is that the unhidden object's tap event also fires at that time. I don't have an extensive background in programming, but I do in software testing so you can expect thorough replication steps. :)

This is the event that fires when any list item is selected:

```
//When a list item is selected
    $('#showItems').delegate('li', 'tap', function () {
        if ($('#showItems').hasClass("courses")){
            courseNum = $(this).find('.course').text();
            var profArr=new Array();
            profArr[0]="";
            profArr[1]="";
            ajax_get_textbooks(courseNum, profArr[1], profArr[0]);
            $('#showItems').removeClass('profs courses booksProf eitems').addClass('books');
        }
        else if ($('#showItems').hasClass("profs")){
            prof = $(this).text();
            profArr = prof.split(", ");
            ajax_get_textbooks(courseNum, profArr[1], profArr[0]);
            $('#showItems').removeClass('profs courses books eitems').addClass('booksProf');
        }
        $('#filters').removeClass('hidden'); // this is the object that gets acted upon incorrectly
    });
```

And this is the event that also gets fired when the **first** list element is selected:

```
//When filter by professor/e-resources is selected
 $('.filterBtn').bind('tap',function(event){
    var filter = $(this).text();
    filter = filter.toLowerCase();
    if (filter.indexOf("prof") !== -1 ) {
        ajax_filter_professor(courseNum);
        $('#showItems').removeClass('books courses booksProf eitems').addClass('profs');
    }
    else {
        ajax_filter_eresources(courseNum);  
        $('#showItems').removeClass('books profs booksProf courses').addClass('eitems');
    }
    $('#showItems').listview('refresh');
});
```

I thought I could work around this problem by attaching the taphold event to the same function, but the following line doesn't work:

```
$('#showItems').delegate('li', 'tap taphold', function () {
```

It only works when I copy the same code into a new event trigger for taphold.

I'd like to be able to somehow disable the $('.filterBtn').bind until the first list has finished refreshing, but can't figure out how to do that.

Here are the **replication steps**

1. http://library.iit.edu/mbad/#textbooks
   Enter "hu" in the textbox. Course list propogates.
2. Slect the first list item (HUM102).
3. Notice that your mouse is now hovering over one of the two buttons: "by Prof" or "E-items." If you were testing this on a phone, one of those button events would also fire.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Solved after a long weekend and finding the e.stopPropagation() object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using the vclick event of JQM.
See list of events supported in JQM on http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html
If it is not Vclick something else might fit.